# Get action name in model rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload files in my rail4 project. Now I need to apply some condition based on the name of controller action that is currently uploading the attachment file.

Can someone please help me get the name of currently used action in model.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Here is my code in modal file:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => lambda { |attachment| {:medium =>  attachment.instance.video? ? { :geometry => "236x236>", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 } : { :geometry => "236x236>" }, :thumb => attachment.instance.video? ? { :geometry => "150x150>", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 } : { :geometry => "150x150>" },:large => attachment.instance.video? ? { :geometry => "1000x700", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 } : { :geometry => "1000x700" }} },:processors => lambda { |a| a.video? ? [ :transcoder ] : [ :cropper ] }

before_post_process :is_audio?

def is_audio?
  return false if [ 'audio/mp3','audio/mpeg'].include?(attachment.content_type) 
end
```

Now I want to skip processors and styles and keep only the original file (just like here in case of audio file) if file is uploaded from update action. Please suggest.

Comment: looks like  a wrong approach, pass it as an arg, the model shouldnt be aware of the request directly

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we can help you fix it. Alternatively try the above suggestion, then show us that if you still need help. :)

Comment: I am uploading files with jquery file upload and then applying various processors on it. But what I need is that when I upload files from different action/form, then skip those processors and styles. Is it more clear. :)

Comment: create a method in model and pass the params[:action] to it and then use it..